# how to transfer the menu button from the main menu or parent midi to the mdi child

Tags: vb6

The 'Menu' and 'View All' appears below the title bar of the midi parent

[image: What appears when]

Instead of like this one

[image: It should be like this]

The first photo is set in mdi parent and child form but then the menu does not appear the right way. How can I make it appear in the mdi child? Or if its not possible, how can I delete/remove it?

Comment: When an mdi child has a menu defined on it, and it gains focus, the child menu is automatically displayed on the mdi parent. No way to change that behavior, as far as I know, at least with standard vb6 functionality.

Comment: @MarkL Thank you for that. I just deleted it and used a toolbar since that's the case.

Comment: It's MDI not "midi"

Comment: @DaveInCaz thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to change the behavior. Deleted the menu and added toolbar instead.